# Listing Azure Blobs With Pagination

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, .net-5

Suppose I have thousands of files in Azure blob Storage and I want to get one page at a time (it is not good idea to load entire pages). But I couldn't get any idea how to proceed.
I tried like this : [List blobs with Azure Storage client libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list?tabs=dotnet).

This is my code :

```
public async Task<BlobPageDto> GetBlobPageAsync
            (string containerName, int? segmentSize, string? continuationToken)
        {
            var blobPage = new BlobPageDto();

            try
            {

                BlobClient? blobClient = null;

                var client = new BlobContainerClient(_connectionString, containerName);
                await client.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

                // Call the listing operation and return pages of the specified size.
                var resultSegment = client.GetBlobsAsync()
                    .AsPages(continuationToken, segmentSize);
                await foreach (var page in resultSegment)
                {
                    var blobItems = new List<BlobItemDto>();
                    foreach (var item in page.Values)
                    {
                        blobClient = client.GetBlobClient(item.Name);
                        string blobUrl = blobClient.Uri.ToString();

                        blobItems.Add(
                            new()
                            {
                                Name = item.Name,
                                Url = blobUrl
                            });
                    }

                    blobPage = new() { BlobItems = blobItems, ContinuationToken = page.ContinuationToken };
     break; //to get one page
                }
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException e)
            {
                
            }

            return blobPage;
        }
```

**BlobItemDto.cs**

```
public class BlobItemDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
        public string Url { get; set; } = default!;
    }
```

**BlobPageDto.cs**

```
public class BlobPageDto
    {
        public IEnumerable<BlobItemDto>? BlobItems { get; set; }
        public string? ContinuationToken { get; set; }
    }
```

**Update:**
From above code How I can achieve the pagination like this (since by using `ContinuationToken` I can only move forward):
[image: Pagination Demo]

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you’ve written and the issues you’re running into.

Comment: I have edited my question. The code in my question is fetching entire pages. But I don't want the entire collection to be loaded. Only one page is enough.

Comment: upon subsequent request I'll pass  `ContinuationToken ` to get next page.

Comment: Thanks. Is your code not breaking out of the loop after fetching a page?

Comment: yes it is breaking. but I'm getting same continuation token & it never becomes null.

Comment: @Shameem why would the continuation token be null? Why is it a problem for you that it isn't?

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri. It was my fault, I'm passing wrong container name & I'm expecting the continuation token to be null after certain pages.

Comment: @TomW thanks, it should be null, when it reached last page.

Comment: I updated my question with actual problem.